# Can't find template and add page WinUI3 in "Add new Item" dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

I created the project for WinUI3 and tried to add page xaml with "Add new Item" dialog using right click on project in Solution explorer.

But I can't find template and add page WinUI3 in "Add new Item" dialog.

Comment: You are probably running into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6583).

Answer (score 1):

Did You install tools for the Windows App SDK?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app#msix-packaged-create-a-new-project-for-an-msix-packaged-c-or-c-winui-3-desktop-app

From step 1:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b

Or select group:
[picture - WinUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxZ8m.png)